# GCC -Wconversion warns in conjunction with negation, but not otherwise

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point, gcc-warning

Take this piece of code:

```
int main()
{
  short a = 2, b = 1;
  float f = 5.36f;

  -a * f;
  b * f;
}
```

Compile:

```
~ $ g++ -std=c++11 wconversion.cpp -Wconversion
wconversion.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
wconversion.cpp:6:8: warning: conversion to ‘float’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
   -a * f;
```

Why does it warn for `a`, but not for `b`?

EDIT: Since it seems that it depends on the compiler version: I'm using GCC 4.9. Also, the behavior is the same in other code where `a` and `b` are not constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What does the warning mean?

Some values of a 32-bit type `int` cannot be represented exactly as `float`. If such an `int` value is converted to `float`, the nearest `float` will be picked (the choice between the two surrounding floats is implementation-defined, but nearly all implementations pick the nearest one).

The warning appears to be about this loss of information during the conversion from `int` or a wider integer type to `float`.

### Should a smart compiler warn for `b`?

A smart compiler doesn't need to emit a warning for `b`, because `b` is a `short` (presumably 16-bit on the OP's architecture), and all the values `b` could have at run-time can be represented exactly as `float`.

### Should a smart compiler warn for `-a`?

A smart compiler could avoid warning for `a` for the same reason. `-a` has type `int` because of promotions, but the values of `-a` range from -(2<sup>15</sup>-1) to 2<sup>15</sup> (on the OP's platform). All these values can be represented exactly as float. However, the general warning that appears to be triggered here is for an expression of type `int` or wider. GCC does not seem to be able to detect that the situation the message warns about cannot arise.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the version of gcc.  With 4.4.5 I get a warning on both lines:

```
foo.c:2: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:6: warning: conversion to ‘float’ from ‘int’ may alter its value
foo.c:6: warning: statement with no effect
foo.c:7: warning: conversion to ‘float’ from ‘int’ may alter its value
foo.c:7: warning: statement with no effect
foo.c:8: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

Perhaps the developers made a special case, recognizing that `b` is "1" and there is an exact conversion, while a "-2" runs into a potential ambiguity on the user's part (except for special cases, conversion will round off - and the heuristic may need refinement).  With gcc 4.9, I get only one warning:

```
foo.c:1:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
 int main()
 ^
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:6:6: warning: conversion to ‘float’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
   -a * f;
      ^
foo.c:6:3: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
   -a * f;
   ^
foo.c:7:3: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
   b * f;
   ^
foo.c:8:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
```

Comment: Updated my question, I'm using 4.9, and the warnings are the same for code where `a` and `b` are not constant.